# Apache - Can't access xampp server through another device

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, wifi, lan

I have just set up a wi-fi network from my mobile (Android). I have all my files on my desktop computer (192.168.43.212) and want to access localhost over there from my mobile that used for the wi-fi network.

On my desktop I can access localhost through the normal [http://localhost] or [http://192.168.43.212]. Apache is running on port 80 as usual.

But I can't access it on my mobile using [http://192.168.43.212]. My desktop computer runs in Windows 7 and I've turn off the firewall but still not working.

Comment: your desktop is connected to same wifi?
what is your devices ip address

Comment: Yes, of course. I've try to ping via terminal emulator to my desktop computer and it runs correctly. But I still can't access xampp on my mobile :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use photon browser on the web-stores, but it doesn't work for normal browsers on mobile devices due to their operating system's security.

Comment: If you have any working example then share it otherwise post this solution as a comment not an answer because its authenticity is difficult to verify.